# Глаголы у слова "искушение"

Tags: лексика

Приведите, пожалуйста, глагольно-именные сочетания со словом "Искушение"? Допустимы ли выражения претерпеть (терпеть) искушение (я), испытывать искушение.

Comment: Можно, не дожидаясь ответа, заглянуть в НК РЯ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Терпеть искушение, претерпеть искушение - самые распространённые сочетания в религиозном смысле.

Принять искушение (согласиться его терпеть), впасть в искушение, вводить в искушение.

Испытывать искушение - более современное, светское (не религиозное) сочетание.

Answer (score 1):

Много чего может быть, можно и "испытывать" искушение (что-либо сделать или съесть).
Поддаться искушению, удержаться от искушения, противостоять искушению, подвергнуть кого-л. искушению, вызвать у кого-л. искушение, пробудить в ком-л. искушение, бороться с искушением...

Comment: А может ли сочетание "испытывать искушение" означать: стремиться к нему, но противиться, чувствовать позыв к искушению?

Comment: Испытывает - кто-то или что-то его уже искушает; стремится к нему -  хочет, чтобы его искушали, хочет узнать, сможет ли противостоять; противится искушению - его искушают, но он не поддаётся, противится; чувствовать позыв = что-то внутри стремится к искушению. Это разные значения. Может, Вас заинтересует "предвкушал искушение" - предчувствовал его появление и не против был его претерпеть, испытать себя. Только тогда уж "предвкушал соблазн, а то тавтология получается"

Comment: @Владимир _Испытывать искушение_ значит _иметь противоречивое желание_ (сделать что-то возможное и заманчивое).